# Updating a multi-valued field in ApacheSolr

Tags: solr

I've been using ExternalFileField for external scoring so far, so that
the external field gets "updated" and not "deleted and added"

Now, I have a field which is multivalued. I cannot use
ExternalFileField as I need this field in the suggest component too.

Is there something other than ExternalFileField which will help me in
doing this?

Thanks!